# Can Flink send files with sink specific S3 Server Side Encryption Headers?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, server-side, flink-streaming

Trying to send records to Amazon S3 with Flink: however these records need to be sent with an AES256 SSE header to request server side encryption

see aws documentation:
If you need server-side encryption for all of the objects that are stored in a bucket, use a bucket policy. For example, the following bucket policy denies permissions to upload an object unless the request includes the x-amz-server-side-encryption header to request server-side encryption:

Is this something that can be set for specific file sinks? have not found any documentation on the matter and beginning to think a forwarding lambda will be needed to transform the data.